# Cannot start gii generator

Tags: yii, gii

I am trying to start gii generator but for some reason it doesn't start. I am working in web server not in my localhost. 
I set the gii in the config file like this:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*', '192.168.178.20', '195.178.49.18'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: you are getting any error?

Comment: I type in the browser the following link - https://"project domain"/index.php?r=gii - and I get to my project's page which says "page not found".

Comment: https://"project domain"/index.php/gii ..If you try this also same message you are getting?

Comment: I also use https://"hostname"/index.php?r=gii - and in this case it says "site can't be reached". As I am working on web server I think using https://"hostname"/index.php?r=gii - is not logical.

Comment: you are using yii or yii2?

Comment: yes I get the same message

Comment: I am using yii 2.

Comment: if do like this `if (!YII_ENV_DEV) {`

Comment: no use, the same result

Comment: @RasimAgayev are you on the list of allowed IPs?

Comment: yes, I am in the list

Answer (score 0):

If you have not setted  an urlmanager for prettyUrl You should use the default routing sintax

```
 https://your_app/web/index.php?r=gii
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its too late now to answer, but not too late.
if you'r using advance template,  then you need to add your IP in your `backend/config/main-local.php` or `frontend/config/main-local.php`.
Basically you have to add your ip for both ends.
if you are not sure about your ip, then you can use '*' for allowing all ip(dont forget to change it after work in done), like -> `'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.33.1', '*.*.*.*']` .

```html
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '*.*.*.*']
        ];
```